# SocketException when connecting to a database after once successfully connceting

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building a MySQL class to connect to a MySQL database. When initially connecting to the database, any data requested via a `SELECT` statement is returned as expected. When attempting to connect for the second time, a `SocketException` is thrown.

Here's the current implementation of the `SELECT` method

```
public DataSet Select(string command)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

This method is called from a foreach loop like so

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> i in sqlCalls)
{
    Select(i.Value);
}
```

And here's the error thrown when the second call is made

> **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:** 'Fatal error encountered during command execution.'
>
> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Am I not disposing of something correctly in the first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, my connection string was the following

```
Server=[server];Database=[db];Port=3306;Uid=[uid];Pwd=[pwd];Connect Timeout=120;
```

I added several debug commands to time the command and noted the command was timing out after 60 seconds. This puzzled me, as the connection timeout was already set. I decided to look into the documentation for the `MySqlCommand` class and noticed the [CommandTimeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_CommandTimeout.htm) property.

After explicitly defining this property, all is working. Here's the full implementation;

```
    public DataSet Select(string command)
    {
        string connString = LoadConnectionString();
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(conn.State);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

Comment: interesting, I didn't have to do it. Which mysql library version are you using ?

Comment: This is using MySQL.Data v8.0.18, how bizzaire that you didn't have to go this route!

Comment: maybe because I didn't put Connect Timeout=120; in the connection string as well

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar and I open and close the connection explicitly:

```
public DataSet Select(string command)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {

        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, hasn't fixed it but it was worth a shot. I'm going to have to investigate further. There's a non-zero chance I've done something silly here.

Comment: is there a chance the server is denying the connection attempt ?

Comment: Possibly. I wouldn't see why though; I've implimented a similar process in Python and it's worked flawlessly. Either way, I'll update the post when I've found out.

Comment: I've now added an answer